# How can I add a created Google Map ID (with a Style) to an iframe embed?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, embed

I have to embed an GoogleMap via iframe in a WordPress element.
I have an api key and added this to the url.
I also created a mapID and created a mapStyle and linked the style to the map in GoogleMapsPlatform.

My question: how can I link **this** map (with the connected style) to this iframe/url:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" style="border:0" loading="lazy" allowfullscreen src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJU55bASnfx0cRjHv5JZmA4p8&key=MY_KEY_HERE"></iframe>
```

Or can it not work like this?

Comment: What API are you using? Maps Embed API does not allow map styles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that way indeed. For now I made a visual in a styled map style and used this which links to GoogleMaps.